# Doubts about objects with arrays inside - Riot Api

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to parse data from Riot API to C# objects

```
    public SpectatorDTO GetSpectator(string encryptedSummonerId)
    {
        string path = "spectator/v4/active-games/by-summoner/" + encryptedSummonerId;
        var response = GET(GetURI(path));
        string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpectatorDTO>(content);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And I get a Json with a list of Participants

```
{
    "gameId": 1966910640,
    "mapId": 11,
    "gameMode": "CLASSIC",
    "gameType": "MATCHED_GAME",
    "gameQueueConfigId": 420,
    "participants": [
        {
            "teamId": 100,
            "spell1Id": 12,
            "spell2Id": 4,
            "championId": 67,
            "profileIconId": 4447,
            "summonerName": "Reversed1",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "uF6aT7haL0MrhHOE6toi2f3ADnmCrO0NGumVtpYYAnwZBw",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8005,
                    9111,
                    9104,
                    8014,
                    8139,
                    8135,
                    5005,
                    5008,
                    5002
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8000,
                "perkSubStyle": 8100
            }
        },
        {
            "teamId": 100,
            "spell1Id": 3,
            "spell2Id": 4,
            "championId": 432,
            "profileIconId": 20,
            "summonerName": "scamber2",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "2OjE7xF-CgcWmgbXX-s9rQ5G1QszQVXn72U_WSMAcidcfZ4",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8465,
                    8463,
                    8473,
                    8453,
                    8136,
                    8106,
                    5005,
                    5002,
                    5002
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8400,
                "perkSubStyle": 8100
            }
        },
        {
            "teamId": 100,
            "spell1Id": 7,
            "spell2Id": 4,
            "championId": 21,
            "profileIconId": 3161,
            "summonerName": "My4tune",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "HQUq_2hbyVZC0i5G7wPz5CKPP2fQqNWzKI_ZCpmXmjH6sQ",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8229,
                    8226,
                    8233,
                    8236,
                    9103,
                    8014,
                    5005,
                    5008,
                    5002
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8200,
                "perkSubStyle": 8000
            }
        },
        {
            "teamId": 100,
            "spell1Id": 4,
            "spell2Id": 14,
            "championId": 42,
            "profileIconId": 4082,
            "summonerName": "SLIDE THE PRIME",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "sqNgBNdcYRA4iL3UkZdJP4g_gcnNjZa11sHbEE5FjZZK",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8021,
                    8009,
                    9103,
                    8014,
                    8304,
                    8345,
                    5005,
                    5008,
                    5003
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8000,
                "perkSubStyle": 8300
            }
        },
        {
            "teamId": 100,
            "spell1Id": 4,
            "spell2Id": 11,
            "championId": 76,
            "profileIconId": 1666,
            "summonerName": "apenas o jacoba",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "Ol-uUb63INHQ_yUFBIX-6zVK1H9vUCUjMDLhpzJG6jCR",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8112,
                    8126,
                    8138,
                    8134,
                    8232,
                    8275,
                    5005,
                    5008,
                    5002
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8100,
                "perkSubStyle": 8200
            }
        },
        {
            "teamId": 200,
            "spell1Id": 4,
            "spell2Id": 11,
            "championId": 48,
            "profileIconId": 27,
            "summonerName": "Purplera1n",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "Cqn4zGG1aUhrdlRTd5h1T4GY5e3xA92yDeMU9-26nyOTaA",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8230,
                    8275,
                    8234,
                    8232,
                    9111,
                    9104,
                    5005,
                    5008,
                    5003
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8200,
                "perkSubStyle": 8000
            }
        },
        {
            "teamId": 200,
            "spell1Id": 4,
            "spell2Id": 14,
            "championId": 555,
            "profileIconId": 3150,
            "summonerName": "crispamdomi",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "Rse0J0aj4jmwu_5dOSLA-nm5jsA_fpQKZqC3UxXCCOIgbw",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8439,
                    8446,
                    8473,
                    8453,
                    8009,
                    9105,
                    5008,
                    5008,
                    5002
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8400,
                "perkSubStyle": 8000
            }
        },
        {
            "teamId": 200,
            "spell1Id": 12,
            "spell2Id": 4,
            "championId": 114,
            "profileIconId": 4353,
            "summonerName": "Switch Dancer",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "gIF0bhyvdqN8fQuKXESnMjr53zcafhxuytCxYgkd-wBCzIc",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8010,
                    9101,
                    9104,
                    8299,
                    8444,
                    8451,
                    5005,
                    5008,
                    5002
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8000,
                "perkSubStyle": 8400
            }
        },
        {
            "teamId": 200,
            "spell1Id": 4,
            "spell2Id": 7,
            "championId": 236,
            "profileIconId": 503,
            "summonerName": "HadesEx",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "zcCuPU6S31itm5kU8AoVpi0gsEfYuV9EFzJq53wts_he",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8005,
                    9111,
                    9103,
                    8014,
                    8275,
                    8236,
                    5005,
                    5008,
                    5002
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8000,
                "perkSubStyle": 8200
            }
        },
        {
            "teamId": 200,
            "spell1Id": 12,
            "spell2Id": 4,
            "championId": 268,
            "profileIconId": 4568,
            "summonerName": "Gabriel halier",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "hmH47acdpzz8Tpo9erJ9pCx7i0YmatOQQFcpZdwvwa_6Dr0",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8008,
                    8009,
                    9104,
                    8014,
                    8226,
                    8210,
                    5005,
                    5008,
                    5003
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8000,
                "perkSubStyle": 8200
            }
        }
    ],
    "observers": {
        "encryptionKey": "kh6jIgM5QzDwKHQ93bmTgpE/KHfT45vT"
    },
    "platformId": "BR1",
    "bannedChampions": [
        {
            "championId": 412,
            "teamId": 100,
            "pickTurn": 1
        },
        {
            "championId": 39,
            "teamId": 100,
            "pickTurn": 2
        },
        {
            "championId": -1,
            "teamId": 100,
            "pickTurn": 3
        },
        {
            "championId": 11,
            "teamId": 100,
            "pickTurn": 4
        },
        {
            "championId": -1,
            "teamId": 100,
            "pickTurn": 5
        },
        {
            "championId": 30,
            "teamId": 200,
            "pickTurn": 6
        },
        {
            "championId": 111,
            "teamId": 200,
            "pickTurn": 7
        },
        {
            "championId": -1,
            "teamId": 200,
            "pickTurn": 8
        },
        {
            "championId": 110,
            "teamId": 200,
            "pickTurn": 9
        },
        {
            "championId": 60,
            "teamId": 200,
            "pickTurn": 10
        }
    ],
    "gameStartTime": 1591400729765,
    "gameLength": 395
}
```

[Image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ661.png)

I trying to put values into SpectatorDTO using lists, arrays and dictionary but I get an error everytime.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path 'participants', line 1, position 119.'

```
    public class SpectatorDTO
{
    public string SummonerId { get; set; }
    public int championId { get; set} ;
    public Dictionary<int, int> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

}

I just want to get a ID from champions on that list/json

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you without seeing the structure of `SpectatorDTO`.

Comment: That JSON is not “a list of Participants”, it is a record containing a list of many things including Participants, each of which is not a `SpectatorDTO`, so `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpectatorDTO>` is not going to work at all. If you explained what “a ID from the specific champion” means we may be able to help.

Comment: @DourHighArch this json has a 10 championId, for example "championId": 42" is included on Participants[3], I want know how I can find and use those values